# launch application from browser url scheme

Tags: android, android-intent

Thanks to many good posts, I have bee trying to launch my Android app from a browser link using the following code. Please help me adjust the manifest and href to call my application -

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.afs"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.1">
  <supports-screens
  android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"></uses-sdk>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/afs"        android:debuggable="true">
      <activity android:name=".afs"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
         <intent-filter>
             <data android:scheme="afs.com.afs"/>
             <data android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         </intent-filter>    
    </activity>
</application>
```

HTML code

```
<a href="afs.com.afs:75235">Launch Application</a>
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Attributes from [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)   `scheme://host:port/path` or `pathPrefix` or `pathPattern`.

You need to change define proprely scheme and host definition. If you don't specify scheme then all URI attributes will be ignored, and won't be applied.

You could use `http` URI scheme.

```xml
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="afs.com.afs"/>
```

and in HTML

```html
<a href="http://afs.com.afs:75235">Launch Application</a>
```

Or define own URL scheme.

```html
    <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="afs.com.afs"/>
```

and in HTML

```
<a href="myapp://afs.com.afs:75235">Launch Application</a>
```

PS.

Change this

```
    <data android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

to

```html
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

Comment: It worked and thanks again for helping out. I clicked that it was helpful. I hope that is what I needed to do to credit your answer as the solution.

Comment: Just to know that, what if the app is not installed?

Comment: Usually you should use http or https scheme with valid host (which you can manage). So if a user has installed your app, it will launch it automatically. Otherwise, user will be forwarded to the browser where you can do whatever you want. e.g. Redirect him to the App listing on Google Play Store. Additionally you can use Referrer parameter to pass some additional data to the application after user's installed it during that process. https://blog.branch.io/technical-guide-to-android-deep-linking-google-play-referrer