# Android open activity from browser

Tags: java, android, android-intent, intentfilter

I want to open my app using a url scheme, I searched on google an SO and found the below code.that people are saying that is working. but it is not working for me:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="shan"/>                
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have specified the above in my manifest under the activity. and when i type `shan://` from browser, it does not open the application.

any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Seem like duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644712/launch-application-from-browser-url-scheme

Comment: i have answered my own question. i'll accept it in two days.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and figure it out myself. Dont know it is the same problem. Refer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13044911/1503155
My problem was I set android:exported to false. 
android:exported="true" should be set to true not false.

Answer (score 0):

its working .. the problem was with android browser, when i was putting the scheme in the url bar. it was treating it as a search term ( dont know why ). i then created a sample web page with a href and its working when i click the href.

Comment: Some browser take input text as Search string if it is not a url, like if you put search string in Google Chrome, and that text is not a url, it will go to google search by default, i think this was happening in your case too.