# Display website outside of android application and return to android application from website

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, web

Basically, my objective is to create a android application where by when a frame marker is detected,  a particular website will be displayed.  In the website, there can be a button whereby when i click the button, the website will be closed and the android application will be opened again.

I am now able to detect frame marker and display a website. However i am not sure how to return back to the android application from the website.

Hope someone can give me advise or hint as to how i can return back to the android application from the website.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a url scheme to your app.

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.customname."/>
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644712/launch-application-from-browser-url-scheme).

Here is [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html).

Answer (score 0):

try using deep links.
deep links can be used to point your application.