# How to deep link computer software from a website link Like "ZOOM"?

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, backend

I am making an app (webapp) but in executable stand alone with
help of electron js i have made the application in python django(backend)
if I want to open my application by just a click (link or in form of a alert)
LIKE **ZOOM** does. I gives a link by click which a site opens and by which alerts you to open the zoom application. So how can I do this by clicking  a link it opens a software.

PLZ HELP!!

Comment: This feature makes use of the **protocol** part of URL syntax. You're probably familiar with `http://` or `ftp://` but you can also create a link with your own protocol such as `zoom://` or `srivastava://`. The browser will not know what to do with such a link when you click it so the browser will ask you how you want to open the link. This is where you tell the browser to open the link in your app and the browser will remember it. That's also how `torrent:` links work

Answer (score 0):

You set the protocol of the link to your app, e.g. myapp:// instead of https:// and then install a handler for the URL scheme on the device. The latter is platform dependent, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/497146/create-a-custom-url-protocol-handler or [launch application from browser url scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13644712/launch-application-from-browser-url-scheme)